grpc-gateway: Context being passed to http handler losing values set on context
I'm at a loss with what is going on with my context between my GRPC handler and it calling gwmux.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx)
I've stripped out a lot of the code to try and only include the bare bones.  None of the values in my context are included in the context once I receive the call to myHttp from gwmux.ServeHTTP.  Is there something I'm missing to ensure the context values are included?
gwmux := runtime.NewServeMux()

r.PathPrefix("/route").HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := r.Context()
        // This works and has the value I expect
        test := ctx.Value("mykey")
        gwmux.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
}


func myHttp(ctx context.Context) {
     // This does not work, it is nil
     test := ctx.Value("mykey")
}



This was a set up issue with the way we were using bootstrap to set up our middleware layer.  Basically before the request was passed to the HTTP the context was completely being replaced rather than added to and passed in.  Once we fixed our middleware, the context maintained the values like we expected.

how did you fix your middleware?
